# How to resolve fatal: $HOME not set error?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-push, git-config

I am running `git config --system user.email "<email>"` on linux via Azure-pipleine.yml file.

After which I get, `fatal: $HOME not set`
What is this error and how can I resolve this ?

Comment: You generally want to set `user.email` when you run a write action afterwards (e.g : `git commit` or `git tag -a` or ...). Can you describe what you are trying to do with your repository in your pipeline ?

Comment: Short answer is : try running `git config user.email "<email>"` without the `--system` option.

Comment: @LeGEC: according to the Git source, you can't get this particular error unless you use `git config --global`. `--system` would not produce this error. It's a bit puzzling since any Linux setup should always have a `$HOME` setting.

Comment: @LeGEC I am trying to run git push --force origin master.

Comment: ok, side note: it is not good practice to have a CI job run `git push --force` especially on your master branch. This may lead to "hey, where did my commit go ?" situations.

Comment: if your CI job tries to do `git push --force`, it means that at some point before you ran `git commit ...` or `git rebase ...` or a command like that. Which one is it ? do you run only one such command or several ones ?

Comment: a minimum step: replace `git push --force` with `git push --force-with-lease`. If something else updates the `master` branch while the job is running, this will prevent the job from blindly overwriting the `master` branch.

Comment: @LeGEC I am trying to work on code rollback in my master branch, as my master has tags like 1.0.0 then 1.0.1, and I have to revert from 1.0.1 to 1.0.0, what should be the steps. So the steps which I am following are: 1. git checkout master, ````git reset --hard <tagname> and git push --force origin master```` . the git push command here shows the error of SSL. which bring me to the ````git config```` command and that give me $HOME not set error. So here's the whole issue.

Answer (score 0):

(from your comments)

Reverting to a commit and pushing should be done from someone's workstation, with a clone of the repository. No need to go through Azure pipelines for this.

The `user.email` field in git is used to say who has created a commit (the name you see when you run `git log` or you inspect the history of your repo on the web GUI of Devops), it has nothing to do with ssh credentials. ssh credentials should be fixed by using an ssh key recognized by your central Azure Devops repository.

The most common way is to set up your `.ssh/config` file to give the correct ssh key when connecting to your Azure Devops server.